# Prove that rings are isomorphic.

Tags: commutative-algebra

I read a text recently where it was explained how to compute the Hilbert function of $R=\mathbb{C}[x_0,...,x_n]$, as I was reading the author seemed to assume that for $f_1,...,f_i,f_{i+1} \in R$ we have $(R/(f_1,...,f_i))/(f_{i+1}) \cong R/(f_1,...,f_{i+1})$ (also $f_i$ is a NZD in $R/(f_1,...,f_{i-1})$ but I dont know if its needed).

Is the isomorphism valid? It feels like I have misunderstood something, for instance the expression $(R/(f_1,...,f_i))/(f_{i+1})$ doesnt make sense to me, $(f_{i+1})$ is not even and ideal of $R/(f_1,...,f_i)$. Can anyone point out what I am missing?

Comment: This is basically the third isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal $(f_{i + 1}) \leq R$ when considered as an ideal in $R/(f_1, \ldots, f_i)$ is actually the ideal
$$\frac{(f_{i + 1}) + (f_1, \ldots, f_i)}{(f_1, \ldots, f_i)} = \frac{(f_1, \ldots, f_{i + 1})}{(f_1, \ldots, f_i)}.$$
In any quotient ring $R/I$ it's pretty common to denote an ideal $J \leq R/I$ by giving an ideal in $R$ whose image under the quotient map $R \to R/I$ is $J$.

As for why the two rings are isomorphic.  Najib is correct, this is exactly the [third isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem_2) for rings.